# Properly extend constructor with decorators

Tags: typescript, constructor, typescript-decorator

How to properly extend class constructor with decorators without loosing class name and static attributes and methods.

Reading the handbook there is a note that says

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators

```
NOTE  Should you choose to return a new constructor function, 
you must take care to maintain the original prototype. 
The logic that applies decorators at runtime will not do this for you.
```

If I do this - like in the handbook - I lose class name and static methods

```typescript
function my_decorator<T extends { new(...constr_args:any[]):any }>(constr_func:T){

    return class extends constr_func {
        constructor(...args: any[]){
            // DO STUFF
            super(...args);
            // DO STUFF
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to copy all the descriptors of the original class into the new extended class I need to instantiate a variable and assign the extended class to it - without giving a name to the class.

Then loop into the original class descriptor and return the varibale.

```typescript
function my_decorator<T extends {new (...constr_args:any[]):any}>(constr_func: T){

    const ExtClass = class extends constr_func {
        constructor(...args: any[]){
            // DO STUFF
            super(...args);
            // DO STUFF
        }
    }

    for(const property_name of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(constr_func)) {
        const descr = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(constr_func, property_name)!;
        if(property_name != 'prototype')
            Object.defineProperty(ExtClass, property_name, descr);
    }

    return ExtClass;

}
```